# How to get input data from form in node,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a form in my node.js app and I want to take the data from the input fields and send it via POST. The post endpoint works, I tested it with Postman, but when I fill the form it just sends an empty object to the database without the form field information, how can I achieve this? Here is my ejs form:

```
<h1>Create a new post!</h1>
<form action="/post" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="content">Post Content</label>
        <input type="text" id="content" name="content" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="categories">Categories</label>
        <input type="categories" id="categories" name="categories" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="picture">Picture</label>
        <input type="text" id="picture" name="picture" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Create Post!</button>
</form>
```

and my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
// let Post = require('./models/post.model.js');

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(BASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs');
});

app.get('/post', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('post.ejs');
});

app.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // let post = new Post(req.body);
    let post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        postContent: req.body.content,
        categories: req.body.categories,
        date: req.body.date,
        picture: req.body.picture
    }
    collection.insertOne(post)
        .then(post => {
            res.status(200).json({ post })
            console.log(post.title)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('failed')
        });
})

app.listen(PORT);
```

and here is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Post = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    postContent: {
        type: String
    },
    categories: {
        type: Array
    },
    date: {
        type: String
    },
    picture: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', Post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

to this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
```

HTML forms do not send JSON data as a post request instead it sends **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** data which needs to be decoded by body parser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created your mongoose post schema? If so, could you please post it here. You use the mongoose schema to create a new model, as shown in the example below:

```
    app.post("/person", async (request, response) => {
        try {
            var person = new PersonModel(request.body);
            var result = await person.save();
            response.send(result);
        } catch (error) {
            response.status(500).send(error);
        }
    });
```

If your node server is starting up, and you're able to post to mongo, mongoose/DAL layer may be causing the issue.

Here I think you can use a mongoose model instead, it looks like you have that commented out: `// let post = new Post(req.body);`

```
    let post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        postContent: req.body.content,
        categories: req.body.categories,
        date: req.body.date,
        picture: req.body.picture
    }
```